# authOptions is not a valid Route export field

Tags: typescript, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

Here is my authOptions code which is running perfectly on localhost.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The problem that I'm facing while deploying my project on vercel is:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use it like below in app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import authOptions from '../../../../lib/configs/auth/authOptions'

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add the implementation of the "authOptions." Thank you so much for considering it!

Answer (score 1):

the error message:

```
Type error: Route "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route. "authOptions" is not a valid Route export field.
```

// options.ts

```
import prisma from '@/lib/prismadb'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

export default authOptions;
```

// route.ts

```
import authOptions from './options'; // Update the path accordingly
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue using a separate file auth.ts

```
app/lib/auth.ts
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
};
```

and then I imported it inside the route.ts

```
app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { authOptions } from "@/app/lib/auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

the error message says:

```
"authOptions" is not a valid Route export field.
```

you should remove `export` from here

```
// export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {}
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {}
```

since you are exporting this:

```
 export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: But that's not possible bro.. I need to use the authOptions in multiple places of my project. For example: 
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);